# Determine context based on instruction pointer

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, virtual-address-space

I am developing a simulator for which the instruction traces are coming from QEMU emulator. The instruction pointer in the traces are virtual instruction pointer.

My basic understanding of 32-bit Linux operating system is that out of 4GB address space, the lower 3GB i.e. 0-3GB is reserved for the application and the upper 1GB i.e. 3GB-4GB is reserved for the kernel.

Is my basic understanding correct ??

In order to determing the context of an instruction i.e. Kernel or Application, I am using a simple check ip>3G. Is this valid ??

One more thing, does this simple method easily extend to 64 bit operating systems ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are talking about x86.

There are different virtual memory split options in the kernel that can be set in its config file. Take a look at VMSPLIT_* options in [arch/x86/Kconfig](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/Kconfig).

3G / 1G, 2G / 2G, 1G / 3G are all possible.

To reliably check if the address belongs to the user space or the kernel space, you can compare it against `TASK_SIZE` value:

```
static int
is_user_space_address(unsigned long addr)
{
    return (addr < TASK_SIZE);
}
```

Works on both 32-bit and 64-bit x86 systems at least.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can I know the default value of TASK_SIZE for 32-bit and 64-bit Linux kernel ??

Comment: @prathmesh.kallurkar, I suppose, there is no default value because the actual value depends on the kernel configuration. In the most common configurations, `TASK_SIZE` is 0xc0000000 on 32-bit x86 systems and 0xffff880000000000 on x86-64. But again, it would be more reliable to get the actual value from the running system or somehow extract it from the compiled kernel.